# Unit root testing in AR(2) simulated data

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root

I'm teaching a course in time series analysis, and using a lot of R simulation. I've come across the following situation. Consider an AR(2) process with $x_t = x_{t-1} - x_{t-2}+w_t$ where $w_t$ is Normal(0,1) noise. This process has a unit root (two, actually, namely $0.5 \pm i*\sqrt{3}/2$). The code below shows how to simulate the process and one can clearly see that it's not stationary as the variance is increasing over time.

```
set.seed(5)
v_0 <- 1
bad_ar2 <- stats::filter(c(v_0,rnorm(50,0,1)), c(1,-1), method='recursive')
plot(bad_ar2)
```

However, when I run the four unit root tests I know, all four are fooled by this AR(2).

```
adf.test(bad_ar2) # p = 0.02, reject null hyp, conclude it's stationary
pp.test(bad_ar2) # p = 0.04, reject null hyp, conclude it's stationary
kpss.test(bad_ar2) # p = 0.1, fail to reject null hyp of "stationary"
ur.model = ur.ers(bad_ar2)
summary(ur.model) # Value of test-statistic is: -2.7164, so reject null of unit root. Wrong.
```

The same thing happens with a seed of 0, 1, and 2. The odds of this happening due to chance alone are slim. It also happens if the sample size is increased from 50 to 500.

The situation of stationarity for an AR(2) process is characterized by [this triangle](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Stationarity-triangle-for-AR2-time-series_fig2_324780859). When you pick $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ outside the triangle, the process won't be stationary and most of the time in my simulations, at least one of the four tests correctly detects that. Same story picking the top point of the triangle or the left or right edge. For $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ inside the triangle, the tests usually correctly tell you the time series is stationary. But the bottom edge, like the example above, seems to fool the tests. Here's my question:

> Is there a unit root test that works to detect non-stationarity like the case described here?

Comment: When you say `reject null hyp of "no unit root"` did you intend to say `reject null hyp of "unit root"`?

Comment: The model you are analyzing is not AR(2) as it is missing the error term.

Comment: @RichardHardy: I respect your answers on this site a lot, but I feel your comment is splitting hairs. In the simulation, surely the error term is present. You've pointed out a typo, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I have been reading the original paper behind the Elliott, Rothenberg & Stock Unit Root Test, and I've learned that the null hypothesis is that the given time series is "integrated of order one." I tried running `diff(bad_ar2)` and learned that mine still looks far from stationary. Maybe this is why the ERS test is getting it wrong. Maybe it's why all the tests are getting it wrong. Still, I'd love to find a test that actually works for $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ on the bottom edge of the triangle I linked.

Comment: @DavidWhite I do think it is a typo, and an important one - hence my comment. Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test) "an augmented Dickey–Fuller test (ADF) tests the null hypothesis that a unit root is present in a time series sample" and then [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phillips%E2%80%93Perron_test) "the Phillips–Perron test (named after Peter C. B. Phillips and Pierre Perron) is a unit root test. That is, it is used in time series analysis to test the null hypothesis that a time series is integrated of order 1."

Comment: Meanwhile it [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPSS_test) "Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin (KPSS) tests are used for testing a null hypothesis that an observable time series is stationary around a deterministic trend (i.e. trend-stationary) against the alternative of a unit root." Getting the null hypothesis correct should matter as otherwise your question gets misinterpreted

Comment: @Henry Ah, yes, you are right. The null hypothesis of ADF (and PP) is "H_0: there is a unit root" , and the alternative is "stationary." I'm using the package `tseries`. If you have that package installed the run the code above you will see something like 
`Dickey-Fuller = -5.8637, Lag order = 7, p-value = 0.01`
`alternative hypothesis: stationary`

Comment: @Henry I've been reading the original KPSS paper from 1992 and they include two versions of their test. In one, the null hypothesis is that it's level stationary. In the other, the null hypothesis is that the input is trend stationary. In the `tseries` package the default is the test of level stationary. If you fed it a trend stationary time series it would reject the null.